# badly formed hexadecimal UUID string in DJANGO

Tags: django, django-models, uuid

I first created a user table in user_app where it would fill the ID of every user normally like 1,2,3,4... so on .

```
class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    user_id = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True)
```

Later i updated the BigAutoField to UUIDField :

```
class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    user_id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True,default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
```

now in database there are some users who has 1,2,3,4.. so on as id and remaining has id in UUID format .
Everything is working fine but the issue here is whenever is click on users in ADMIN panel it shows me the error

```
 value = uuid.UUID(value)
File "C:\Users\divit\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\uuid.py", line 169, in 
__init__
raise  ValueError('badly formed hexadecimal UUID string')
ValueError: badly formed hexadecimal UUID string
```

is there any way to update the ID of other users with 1,2,3..so on as id or is there a way to delete these users? as i cant delete it from admin panel because whenever i click on users it shows me badly  formed hexadecimal UUID string error

Comment: DJango aims to read the integer as a UUID string, and this thus fails, because `1` and `2` are not UUIDs.

Comment: Generally you should have done this in multiple steps, i.e. 1. Add a new field for uuid with it being nullable. 2. Make a data migration to populate this field. 3. Change this new field to be the pk and delete the old field (plus rename if needed). If you don't mind losing the database (And are not in production) just drop / delete it (Also delete your migrations and make new ones).